# Unable to send image in IOS notification FCM

Tags: java, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using post request to send FCM notifications through JAVA on web, android and IOS application. Notifications are going properly just on IOS image is not appearing.

Below is my code

```
JSONObject notificationJson = new JSONObject();

            if (platform == Constants.FCM_TOKEN_PLATFORM_WEB) {
                notificationJson.put("title", notification.getTitle());
                notificationJson.put("body", notification.getDescription());
                notificationJson.put("icon", notification.getBigPicture());
                notificationJson.put("click_action", notification.getWebTargetUrl());
            } else if (platform == Constants.FCM_TOKEN_PLATFORM_ANDROID) {
                notificationJson.put("title", notification.getTitle());
                notificationJson.put("body", notification.getDescription());
                notificationJson.put("image", notification.getBigPicture());
            } else if (platform == Constants.FCM_TOKEN_PLATFORM_IOS) {
                notificationJson.put("title", notification.getTitle());
                notificationJson.put("body", notification.getDescription());
                notificationJson.put("image", notification.getIosAttachments());
                notificationJson.put("click_action", notification.getWebTargetUrl());
            }

            JSONObject data = new JSONObject();

            data.put("title", notification.getTitle());
            data.put("body", notification.getDescription());
            data.put("thumbnail", notification.getBigPicture());
            data.put("album", notification.getAlbumId());
            data.put("video", notification.getVideoId());
            data.put("artist", notification.getArtistId());
            data.put("content", notification.getContentId());
            data.put("playlist", notification.getPlaylistId());

            JSONObject jsonFCM = new JSONObject();

            jsonFCM.put("data", data);
            jsonFCM.put("notification", notificationJson);
            jsonFCM.put("registration_ids", list);

            Map<String, Object> fcmResp = sendNotificationToFCM(jsonFCM);
```

Please help me on what I am missing or making any wrong implementation

```
notificationJson.put("icon", notification.getIosAttachments());
notificationJson.put("image", notification.getIosAttachments());
notificationJson.put("media_url", notification.getIosAttachments());
```

i have tried above lines of code but unsuccessful.